# Select element on hover

Tags: jquery

I need to allocate element on a hover effect, but I had a problem:

```
$('html *')
.on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).addClass('hint-mode_show-block');
})
.on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hint-mode_show-block');
})
```

This code allocates all parent elements although I need to select latest level

I need to get an effect as firebug or another browser inspector

Comment: Your selector will go off on any element and will bubble up, since if you hover over a child element you are also hovering over the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stop the bubbling you need to use `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
$('html *')
.on('mouseover', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('hint-mode_show-block');
})
.on('mouseout', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).removeClass('hint-mode_show-block');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$('*')
.on('mouseover', function(e){
e.preventDefault();    
$(this).addClass('hint-mode_show-block');
})
.on('mouseout', function(e){
e.preventDefault();    
$(this).removeClass('hint-mode_show-block');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

Suppose your html looks like

```
<div id="big">
    <p id="big">Hello Big</p>
<div>
    <p id="inner">Inner</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

then you can do this:

```
$("html *").hover(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
   $(e.target).addClass('hint-mode_show-block');
},function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
    $(e.target).removeClass('hint-mode_show-block');
});
```

Working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/fx2HP/